# SimpleInjector and Microsoft Webhook ASP.Net Webhooks

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webhooks, simple-injector

We had been successfully using the [Microsoft ASP.Net Webhooks](https://github.com/aspnet/WebHooks) (specifically the Stripe one) in our WebAPI 2 project with Ninject.  Recently we migrated to SimpleInjector and while everything else went well, we cannot get this webhook processor to work.  It keeps throwing the following exception: `System.MissingMethodException: 'No parameterless constructor defined for this object.'`

The relevant stack traces are:

```
mscorlib.dll!System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(bool publicOnly, bool skipCheckThis, bool fillCache, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark)  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type type, bool nonPublic)  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type type)  Unknown
Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Common.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Utilities.TypeUtilities.GetInstances<Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.IWebHookHandler>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Reflection.Assembly> assemblies, System.Func<System.Type, bool> predicate) Unknown
Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.ReceiverServices.GetHandlers()    Unknown
Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.DependencyScopeExtensions.GetHandlers(System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyScope services = {SimpleInjector.Integration.WebApi.SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver})    Unknown
Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.WebHookReceiver.ExecuteWebHookAsync(string id = "", System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpRequestContext context = {System.Web.Http.WebHost.WebHostHttpRequestContext}, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request = {System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage}, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> actions = {string[1]}, object data = {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject})  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.Start<Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.WebHookReceiver.<ExecuteWebHookAsync>d__22>(ref Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.WebHookReceiver.<ExecuteWebHookAsync>d__22 stateMachine)  Unknown
Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.WebHookReceiver.ExecuteWebHookAsync(string id, System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpRequestContext context, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> actions, object data)   Unknown
Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Stripe.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.StripeWebHookReceiver.ReceiveAsync(string id = "", System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpRequestContext context = {System.Web.Http.WebHost.WebHostHttpRequestContext}, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request = {System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage})    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.Start<Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.StripeWebHookReceiver.<ReceiveAsync>d__15>(ref Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.StripeWebHookReceiver.<ReceiveAsync>d__15 stateMachine)    Unknown
Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Stripe.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.StripeWebHookReceiver.ReceiveAsync(string id, System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpRequestContext context, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request)  Unknown
Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Controllers.WebHookReceiversController.ProcessWebHook(string webHookReceiver = "stripe", string id = "")  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.Start<Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Controllers.WebHookReceiversController.<ProcessWebHook>d__3>(ref Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Controllers.WebHookReceiversController.<ProcessWebHook>d__3 stateMachine)    Unknown
Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Controllers.WebHookReceiversController.ProcessWebHook(string webHookReceiver, string id)  Unknown
[Lightweight Function]  
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.GetExecutor.AnonymousMethod__8(object instance, object[] methodParameters) Unknown
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext controllerContext, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> arguments, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Unknown
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionAsyncCore(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext = {System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext}, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken = IsCancellationRequested = false) Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.Start<System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0>(ref System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0 stateMachine)  Unknown
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionAsyncCore(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Unknown
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionAsync(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Unknown
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.ExecuteAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken = IsCancellationRequested = false) Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.Start<System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2>(ref System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2 stateMachine)    Unknown
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.ExecuteAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)   Unknown
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext controllerContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)   Unknown
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request = {System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage}, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken = IsCancellationRequested = false)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.Start<System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1>(ref System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1 stateMachine)    Unknown
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Unknown
System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)  Unknown
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpRoutingDispatcher.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)    Unknown
System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)   Unknown
System.Web.Http.Cors.dll!System.Web.Http.Cors.CorsMessageHandler.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request = {System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage}, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken = IsCancellationRequested = false)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.Start<System.Web.Http.Cors.CorsMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__0>(ref System.Web.Http.Cors.CorsMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__0 stateMachine)    Unknown
System.Web.Http.Cors.dll!System.Web.Http.Cors.CorsMessageHandler.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)    Unknown
System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)   Unknown
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request = {System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage}, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken = IsCancellationRequested = false) Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.Start<System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<SendAsync>d__0>(ref System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<SendAsync>d__0 stateMachine)  Unknown
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)  Unknown
System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)  Unknown
System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll!System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.ProcessRequestAsyncCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase contextBase = {System.Web.HttpContextWrapper}) Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start<System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<ProcessRequestAsyncCore>d__0>(ref System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<ProcessRequestAsyncCore>d__0 stateMachine)    Unknown
System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll!System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.ProcessRequestAsyncCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase contextBase)   Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.BeginTask(System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> taskFunc, System.AsyncCallback callback, object state = null)  Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()  Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep step = {System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep}, ref bool completedSynchronously = false)  Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception error)   Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback cb)  Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest wr = {System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest}, System.Web.HttpContext context = {System.Web.HttpContext})    Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext = 0x000002226c0521f0, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags)    Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags)   Unknown
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags)   Unknown
[AppDomain Transition]
```

And

```
System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
at Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Utilities.TypeUtilities.GetInstances[T](IEnumerable`1 assemblies, Func`2 predicate)
at Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.ReceiverServices.GetHandlers()
at Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.DependencyScopeExtensions.GetHandlers(IDependencyScope services)
at Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.WebHookReceiver.<ExecuteWebHookAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.StripeWebHookReceiver.<ReceiveAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Controllers.WebHookReceiversController.<ProcessWebHook>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
```

Our global.asax looks like this:

```
var container = new Container();
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();
container.Options.PropertySelectionBehavior = new 
InjectPropertySelectionBehavior();

// Register our stuff

container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

container.Verify();

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new 
SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
```

we're registering the WebHook handler like this:

`container.Register<IWebHookHandler, StripeWebhookHandler>(Lifestyle.Singleton);`

Has anyone gotten this to work with SimpleInjector? Or have any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Why do you think this is related to Simple Injector? Thenstack trace shows no sign of Simple Injector being involved in this.

Comment: That's a good point, looking closer at that stack trace, it's not very helpful.  The reason I suspected it was SimpleInjector is because it worked perfectly fine with Ninject, and this was the only thing that was changed.  I should have noted above that the StripeWebhookHandler class is a class we've defined that inherits WebhookHandler (theirs) and has a constructor with dependencies.

Comment: The stack trace seems to imply that web hooks is resolving an IWebHookHandler by using Activator.CreateInstance on it, which will obviously fail when the type is an interface (web hooks throws a bad exception message). Are you perhaps missing some integration point that redirects the resolving of IWebHookHandler to Simple Injector? Does Ninject have such integration package you used?

Comment: We're using the integration instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/webhooks/receiving/receivers.  Specifically calling `config.InitializeReceiveStripeWebHooks();` in our Web API config setup.  The Ninject packages we used were Ninject, Ninject.Extensions.Factory and Ninject.Web.Common ... nothing out of the ordinary I believe.

Comment: I appreciate your quick responses Steven.  I updated the Stacktrace in the OP to something more useful hopefully.  The one thing I noticed is that StripeWebHookReceiver has 2 constructors, which might be the problem?  I tried registering it explicitly with: `container.Register<StripeWebHookReceiver>(() => new StripeWebHookReceiver(), Lifestyle.Singleton);` but that didn't work

Comment: Although Simple Injector will not be ablento auto-wire a type with multiple constructors, that is clearly not the problem, since Simple Injector is not resolving that type at all. WebHooks tries to create the type itself using default reflection. I think you need to find out hoe to intercept this creation and redirect it to Simple Injector.

Comment: The initial exception was actually more helpful, because it contained generic types of the method being called.

Comment: Ah ok, I've added it back.  Thanks Steven, I'll see if I can intercept it.

Comment: Steven, I'm not so sure this a problem with the webhooks assembly.  I've gotten the pdbs and have been able to debug and see what's going on.  It gets into this function: 
```public static IEnumerable<TService> GetServices<TService>(this IDependencyScope services)
        {
            return services.GetServices(typeof(TService)).Cast<TService>();
        }```
where services does have a valid container with my registration for IWebhookHandler in it.  But when it calls the GetServices line above, it returns an empty enum.  `TService` in this case is `IWebhookHandler`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

IWebhookHandler needs registered as a collection, so doing this:

`container.Collection.Append(typeof(IWebHookHandler), typeof(StripeWebhookHandler));`

instead of:

`container.Register<IWebHookHandler, StripeWebhookHandler>(Lifestyle.Singleton);`

was the trick!

I figured this out by stepping into the source of both the Microsoft Webhook assembly and SimpleInjector and found that when the Webhook assembly asked for all instances of type `IWebhookHandler`, SimpleInjector, in its GetServices implementation was trying to find all `IEnumerable<IWebhookHandler>` instead and so was coming up with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

These kind of exceptions are thrown when trying to resolve a dependency that has parameter constructors but one or more of the parameters has not been registered and thus cannot be resolved, resulting in a fall back to a parameter-less constructor which in certain cases are absent.

Verify that you have registered all the components needed by WebHooks to work.